# Appending a string to each item of an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, append

I have an array and when I try to append a string to it the array converts to a single string.

I have the following data in an array:

```
$Str  
451 CAR,-3 ,7 ,10 ,0 ,3 , 20 ,Over: 41  
452 DEN «,40.5,0,7,0,14, 21 ,  Cover: 4
```

And I want to append the week of the game in this instance like this:

```
$Str = "Week"+$Week+$Str
```

I get a single string:

```
Week16101,NYG,42.5 ,3 ,10 ,3 ,3 , 19 ,Over 43 102,PHI,-  1,14,7,0,3, 24 ,  Cover 4 103,
```

Of course I'd like the append to occur on each row.

Comment: To make things clearer to the observer, I'd recommend renaming your variable, as the name "str" might make folks think you're supposed to have a single scalar string variable...  just a thought!

Answer (score 15):

Instead of a for loop you could also use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet (if you prefer using the pipeline):

```
$str = "apple","lemon","toast" 
$str = $str | ForEach-Object {"Week$_"}
```

**Output:**

```
Weekapple
Weeklemon
Weektoast
```

Comment: I do like this answer.  It's simpler to read and better for one-off scenarios.  However for a lengthier script where more control is required I think my answer is better suited. Just depends on the application.

Comment: I was searching for this kind of answer to add the same string to all the elements of an array!

Answer (score 6):

Another option for PowerShell v4+

```
$str = $str.ForEach({ "Week" + $Week + $_ })
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, which is fast and concise, albeit a bit obscure.

It uses the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based **[`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) with regex `'^'`** which matches the *position* at the start of each input string and therefore effectively *prepends* the replacement string to each array element (analogously, you could use `'$'` to *append*):

```
# Sample array.
$array = 'one', 'two', 'three'

# Prepend 'Week ' to each element and create a new array.
$newArray = $array -replace '^', 'Week '
```

`$newArray` then contains `'Week one', 'Week two', 'Week three'`

To show an **equivalent `foreach` solution**, which is syntactically simpler than a `for` solution (but, like the `-replace` solution above, invariably creates a *new* array):

```
[array] $newArray = foreach ($element in $array) { 'Week ' + $element }
```

<sup>Note: The `[array]` cast is needed to ensure that the result is *always* an array; without it, if the input array happens to contain just *one* element, PowerShell would assign the modified copy of that element *as-is* to `$newArray`; that is, no array would be created.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `"Week"+$Week+$Str`

Because the LHS of the `+` operation is a single string, simple *string* concatenation takes place, which means that the array in `$str` is *stringified*, which by default concatenates the (stringified) elements with a *space* character.

A simplified example:

```
PS> 'foo: ' + ('bar', 'baz')
foo: bar baz
```

**Solution options**:

For *per-element* operations on an array, you need one of the following:

- A **loop *statement***, such as [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) or [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_For).

  - [Michael Timmerman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412927/45375) shows a `for` solution, which - while syntactically more cumbersome than a `foreach` solution - has the advantage of updating the array *in place*.
- A ***pipeline*** that performs per-element processing via the **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet**, as shown in [Martin Brandl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41414475/45375).
- An expression that uses the **[`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)**, as shown in [Patrick Meinecke's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41418366/45375) answer.
- An expression that uses an ***operator* that accepts arrays as its LHS operand** and then operates on each element, such as the `-replace` solution shown above.

**Tradeoffs**:

- Speed:

  - An operator-based solution is fastest, followed by `for` / `foreach`, `.ForEach()`, and, the slowest option, `ForEach-Object`.
- Memory use:

  - Only the `for` option with indexed access to the array elements allows *in-place* updating of the input array; all other methods create a *new* array.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1]  Strictly speaking, what `.ForEach()` returns isn't a .NET *array*, but a collection of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, but the difference usually doesn't matter in PowerShell.</sup>

Comment: Great answer that doesn't rely on looping

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work for prepending/appending text to each line in an array.

Set array $str:

```
$str = "apple","lemon","toast"

$str
apple
lemon
toast
```

Prepend text now:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Str.Count; $i++) {
    $str[$i] = "yogurt" + $str[$i]
}

$str
yogurtapple
yogurtlemon
yogurttoast
```

This works for prepending/appending static text to each line.  If you need to insert a changing variable this may require some modification.  I would need to see more code in order to recommend something.

Comment: I desire to know which is more PowerShell your answer or Martin Brandl's answer?